# HTTP request flow diagram

Tags: node.js, http, web, httprequest, diagram

I build an web application. As I'm starting to document my application, I'm looking for a way to describe the way a user access the website.

For example: the way the authorization works. A user access any url ./*, then if the user has a valid certificate he'll be redirected to registration page, otherwise he'll be redirect to the not authorized page. After I've been going through my known diagrams (programming flowchart, sequence diagram) and not been satisfied, I wonder what other diagrams can describe the given scenario?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to do it using UML.

An [*Sequence Diagram*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_diagram) or an [*Activity Diagram*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_diagram) both are used to model the *flow* inside your application and should well visualize what you're trying to document.